# C error: missing binary operator before token

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I'm working on building a custom version of openwrt with a build tool and keep running into a error I cant seem to fix.

heres the code block its dating back to.

```
#include <signal.h>
#if ! HAVE_STACK_T && ! defined stack_t
typedef struct sigaltstack stack_t;
#endif
#ifndef SIGSTKSZ
# define SIGSTKSZ 16384
#elif HAVE_LIBSIGSEGV && SIGSTKSZ < 16384 
/* libsigsegv 2.6 through 2.8 have a bug where some architectures use
   more than the Linux default of an 8k alternate stack when deciding
   if a fault was caused by stack overflow.  */
# undef SIGSTKSZ
# define SIGSTKSZ 16384
#endif
```

heres the out put error

```
In file included from /usr/include/signal.h:328,
                 from ./signal.h:52,
                 from c-stack.c:49:
c-stack.c:55:26: error: missing binary operator before token "("
   55 | #elif HAVE_LIBSIGSEGV && SIGSTKSZ < 16384
      |                          ^~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Track down what `SIGSTKSZ` is defined to be.

Comment: @Shawn in signal.h?

Comment: What the error message means is that `SIGSTKSV` has been defined somewhere in your build tools to an empty string. Figure out where and fix it.

Comment: Maybe, or maybe in a header it includes.

Comment: see, i dont know  C so im having trouble even finding the correct variable's.

Comment: as I've been looking into it i seen nothing out of the usual. i saw a #include_next that was not highlighted, changed it to just #include and got the same results. @Dúthomhas

Answer (score 1):

Use this patch to fix this problem: /debian/patches/04-fix-sigstksz.patch from this file:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+sourcefiles/m4/1.4.18-5ubuntu1/m4_1.4.18-5ubuntu1.debian.tar.xz

Answer (score 0):

First of all please note that this is not standard C but POSIX extensions. POSIX has the nasty habit of poisoning standard libraries with non-standard, non-conforming extensions.

This means that if you compile with `-std=c17` or equivalent instead of `-std=gnu17` (default), gcc will strip off all non-standard, non-conforming POSIX junk. And then those things will not be found at all even if you include `signal.h`, which in turn can give you very confusing compiler errors.

---

That being said, I think you perhaps meant to do:

```
#elif defined(HAVE_LIBSIGSEGV) && SIGSTKSZ < 16384
```

---

As for how you can find out what `SIGSTKSZ` is without digging through some library header, here's a simple trick that gives you the exact macro definition:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define STR(s) #s
#define WHAT_ARE_YOU(x) puts(STR(x))

int main (void)
{
  WHAT_ARE_YOU(SIGSTKSZ);
}
```

When compiling as GNU C on some random Linux machine, I get `8192`.

You could also do `gcc -E` to view the preprocessor output (which may be a bit confusing to read since it expands all headers). Doing that for the above example gives `puts("8192");`.

Comment: after working on it and changing the code, im getting the same error.

Comment: @Kuro Well, the compiler error means there's a syntax problem somewhere, not necessarily on that same line.

Comment: yeah its also being called on in signal.h though i dont see any issues there other than it being a different include. ```#include_next <signal.h>```